"Unsupported service account" errors from gcloud when deploying --gen2 functions with --build-service-account
gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 488.0.0
alpha 2024.08.09
beta 2024.08.09
bq 2.1.8
core 2024.08.09
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.30
istioctl 1.20.47

I'm at a loss for how to execute the gcloud functions deploy --gen2 command. I can deploy gen1, but gen2 throws indecipherable service account errors.
First going right from the docs: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#basics
gcloud functions deploy sdfsdfsd \
    --gen2 \
    --project="sdfsdf" \
    --region="us-central1" \
    --entry-point=my_func \
    --no-allow-unauthenticated \
    --runtime=python312 \
    --build-service-account="my-cloud-build-acct@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --trigger-http

I get ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Deployment failed: ["params.service_account: must be empty or a service account of format: projects/{PROJECT_ID}/serviceAccounts/{ACCOUNT}"]. Check your build configuration. Already makes no sense because I'm not setting the service account.
Then I set the account with: --service-account="myacct@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com" and I get ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) Deployment failed: ["params.service_account: must be empty or a service account of format: projects/{PROJECT_ID}/serviceAccounts/{ACCOUNT}"]. Check your build configuration..
I can't find any examples of the gcloud cli using this format, but when I try it I get this error: ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Ok], message=[Could not create Cloud Run service sdfsdfsd. serviceAccountName: Unsupported service account: projects/my-project-id/serviceAccounts/myacct@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
I gave the myacct@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com account the following roles:

What do I have to do to get this command to work?
I can deploy gen2 functions through the UI with this service account without issues.

The message is self explicit isn't it?

The answer had nothing to do with the --service-account param even though whenever I modified its format I got DIFFERENT ERRORS!
I left this off initially (edited my post to include it), but I'm using a custom build service account (default is disabled now for security reasons).
It seems this is the correct series of switches:
--build-service-account="projects/{PROJECT_ID}/serviceAccounts/{CLOUD_BUILD_GSA}" \
--service-account="{RUNTIME_GSA}" \

It does mention this format in the docs: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--build-service-account
But the fact that the errors changed in response to modifying the other switch was very confusing. I would open a bug report, but not sure how it would be worded. params.service_account should have been params.build_service_account in the errors.

As you found, the docs are good and, although it's an unusual way to represent a service account, --build-service-account is documented correctly. I suspect (!) that the confusing error results from gcloud functions deploy attempting to confirm the existing of the build service account as it progresses through the deploy. It's going to have to make an additional call to verify that the service account exists and, per the error, this is the confusing params.service_account (it describes the format it's expecting for the build service account).

One useful feature of gcloud is that you can append --log-http to any command and it will show all the REST calls that are being made. This may help clarify things in this case.
